# Regex to find comma only in numbers

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the following substring:

```
substring = ',LimitPrice:8348.5000000000,LimitPriceText:8,348.50,MinMove:25'
```

I wish to remove the comma only where it is in a number, in `8,348.50` in this example.

**Desired output**:

```
',LimitPrice:8348.5000000000,LimitPriceText:8348.50,MinMove:25'
```

What I tried:

```
re.sub('([0-9]),([0-9])', '', substring)
```

**Issue**: this successfully removes only the comma I wish to remove but also removes the number before and after the comma.

Comment: There is no need using any lookbehinds/lookaheads, you have captured the values to keep - just use backreferences in the replacement pattern, `re.sub('([0-9]),([0-9])', r'\1\2', substring)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use lookaheads and lookbehinds:

```
re.sub('(?<=\d),(?=\d)', '', substring)
```

[(interactive demo)](https://regex101.com/r/7B4nPp/1)

This matches a comma with a number both before and after it.

[More info on lookarounds like this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.htmlhttps://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)